# How to detect file drag on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, client-side

I can detect if a file is being dragged on a div by listening to 'dragover' event. But how can I detect if a file is being dragged over the whole HTML page? document.body does not seem to raise the 'dragover' event.

What I intend to do is as soon as a file is dragged over a page, I'll show a hidden div to drop the file on. Just like Gmail.

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

Make a wrapper `<div>` with `height:100%` that contains your entire page and handle its `dragover` event.